# How to prevent JavaScript directory access with htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

I have a website like `http://example.com` but the problem with it is that people are able to get access to my JavaScript by pointing a browser to `http://example.com/js/`.

I have little knowledge of using *.htaccess* files.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent directory listings when a directory is requested (that doesn't contain a `DirectoryIndex`) you can add the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your site:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will result in a 403 Forbidden being served for `http://example.com/js/`, rather than the server generating a directory listing.

As Jobin Jose suggests, you can add a (blank) `index.html` to these folders (the `DirectoryIndex` document). However, you will need to do this for *every* folder and this will serve a blank page (or whatever you decide to put in index.html), returning a successful HTTP status (200 - OK).

However, you can't *reliably* block users from viewing your JavaScript files that you are referencing in your client-side pages.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an `index.html` (with no content) in your `js` folder.

that will prevent listing of your `js` files in the browsers.

no need of `htaccess` usage here. This will prevent your `js` file listing only access with proper `js` file names.

Hope its helps..

Comment: i have tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Which server are you using ? it should works make sure file extension is correct

Comment: i am using heroku